# How to get iso2code from a country name by locale

Tags: java, android, locale, iso

I have a form that user enter a country name, then I have to convert it to iso2 or iso3 code.

How is it possible? I prefer not to use map, as it seems not running on my Android app.

This code is for converthing iso2 to an actual name, I want the other way around:

```
Locale l = new Locale("", "CH");
System.out.println(l.getDisplayCountry());
```

Comment: `l.getCountry()`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#getCountry()

Comment: @Ricardo thanks but it returns the country name. I need something to convert France to FR for example.

Comment: Read the docs I linked: "Returns the country/region code for this locale".

Comment: @Ricardo I know but in actual program it doesn not do that. How ever here is my code, check it please if its what you mean: `Locale l = new Locale("", "France");` `System.out.println(l.getCountry());` for this code the result is FRANCE which supposed to be fr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried Locale.getISO3Country() ?

To actually do the conversion, you might need to loop through all the available locales and look for the one whose getDisplayCountry() matches your input country name.

It doesn't sound efficient (but you said to not use maps), but you might try something like:

```
Locale convertCountryNameToIsoCode(String countryName)
    for(Locale l : Locale.getAvailableLocales()) {
        if (l.getDisplayCountry().equals(countryName)) {
            return l;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#getISO3Country()

However, if the input comes from a web form, than it would be easier to set the country code directly as the web form input value. If the input comes from an Android native App, then I'm not sure but I'd bet you might a similar thing

Comment: Thanks for your help. To use this method should is it right: `convertCountryNameToIsoCode(France)` ??

Comment: It would be really helpful if you let me know the similar solution with map. Maybe my code for map was wrong.

Comment: @user3026034 Well, you might define `Map<String,String> countryCodes` and at some point during the initialization you should do the same loop but rather than `if (...)` you should do `countryCodes.put(name, l.getISO3Country())`. Just be aware that than you're map will be case-sensitive